# Create a custom Facebook Login RelativeLayout and Onclick of this layout, call the facebook login api?

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a custom relative layout for fb login, and on click of this layout, the default fb login button should get triggered for fb login, using fb login api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a much better method, without using GoogleFirebase. Create a layout and onclick of that layout, call LoginButton.performClick();

Answer (score 0):

You can Integrate Facebook Login into your app by Using Google Firebase.

REfer this link:
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login

Comment: There also its using default Facebook Button. i.e. LoginButton.

Comment: I want to use a RelativeLayout

Comment: Try once...Design the button based on your intension and when user click your custom button navigate him to firebse  facebook authentication class.

Comment: Found a much better method, without using GoogleFirebase. Create a layout and onclick of that layout, call LoginButton.performClick();